# Conditionally add keywords to string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

The problem is fairly complex. Let's say the input of my function is a string. The input can contain the following keywords:

- `"{% if some_condition %}"` (Start)
- `"{% endif %}"` (End)
- `"{% else if some_other_condition %}"` (Optional)
- `"{% else %}"` (Optional)

Along with these keywords, the input may also contain any other string. The conditions are basically just names of variables, so within a string before parsing, they are just strings (any valid string is acceptable as a variable name).

Here's what the function is meant to do:

- Take the input and look for start and end tag pairs.
- When found, look inside the contents between the start tag and end tag.
- If the content contains `"{% else if <any_condition> %}"` **OR** `"{% else %}"`, then do nothing.
- Otherwise, add the `"{% else %}<div class='empty'>Empty</div>"` string right at the end of the content.

So for clarity, here is an example **input**:

```
{% if username %}
  <p>Hello {{ username }}</p>
{% endif %}

{% if score > 10 %}
  <p>You are doing great.</p>
{% else if score > 50 %}
  <p>You are freaking amazing!</p>
{% endif %}

<p>This is your <strong>awesome</strong> profile page.</p>

{% if not email %}
  <p>Please consider setting your email address</p>
{% endif %}

{% if balance > 0 %}
  <p>You are ready to go!</p>
{% else %}
  <p>No balance</p>
{% endif %}
```

And the **output** would be the following:

```
{% if username %}
  <p>Hello {{ username }}</p>
{% else %}<div class="empty">Empty</div>{% endif %}

{% if score > 10 %}
  <p>You are doing great.</p>
{% else if score > 50 %}
  <p>You are freaking amazing!</p>
{% endif %}

<p>This is your <strong>awesome</strong> profile page.</p>

{% if not email %}
  <p>Please consider setting your email address</p>
{% else %}<div class="empty">Empty</div>{% endif %}

{% if balance > 0 %}
  <p>You are ready to go!</p>
{% else %}
  <p>No balance</p>
{% endif %}
```

In short, if the contents inside the `if` block doesn't have a conditional, then the extra string is appended right before the closing tag. Hope that makes sense. I know it's a lot to ask for, but could someone just get me started with this in the right direction? I'm not very good with regex using JavaScript, and it's basically kicking my ass. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What you've got so far?

Comment: @vanowm Nothing substantial enough to add to the answer tbh

Comment: Just out of itching curiosity... What are you building? Why you need that strange `<div class="empty">Empty</div>` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Haha just trying to build an experimental templating library.

Comment: @darkhorse I guessed so, but why would a templating library mess with HTML by introducing superfluous tags like that DIV.empty?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, perhaps they should be called placeholder `<div>` instead.

Comment: If I use a templating library, I certainly don't want it to  automagically create strange tags. Just one reason. I might already, as a developer use some `.empty` DIVS of mine, and I certainly don't want to fight a templating engine introducing elements I do not desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like the following. Flag "g" is global, "m" is multiline and "s" is "dotall" mode which means that "." can grab "\n". I grab all the inputs, replace them, see if there's "else if" or "else" therefore replace "{% endif %}" with "{% else %}" plus what you wanted plus "{% endif %}".

```
input.replace(
    /{% if.*?%}.*?{% endif %}/gms,
    match => 
        (!/(else if|else)/.test(match))
            ? match.replace(
                /{% endif %}/,
               '{% else %}<div class="empty">Empty</div>{% endif %}'
              )
            : match
);

/*{% if username %}
  <p>Hello {{ username }}</p>
{% else %}<div class="empty">Empty</div>{% endif %}

{% if score > 10 %}
  <p>You are doing great.</p>
{% else if score > 50 %}
  <p>You are freaking amazing!</p>
{% endif %}

<p>This is your <strong>awesome</strong> profile page.</p>

{% if not email %}
  <p>Please consider setting your email address</p>
{% else %}<div class="empty">Empty</div>{% endif %}

{% if balance > 0 %}
  <p>You are ready to go!</p>
{% else %}
  <p>No balance</p>
{% endif %}*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This almost works, but the resulting output is an array that leaves out any possible things that may be outside of the `if` start and end tag pairs. I've updated the original question with a better input and output example.

Comment: Yep looks like it. I was seriously expecting it to be a giant solution, but this is amazing. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well man I've recently studied regex and become pretty mad making crazy evolutions, now I feel pretty confident with them! xD The last thing I've made for a project on Context-free Grammar is `/^ *\\[\\[ *([^{}[\\]]+?) *=( *{{ *([^|]+?( *\\| *([^: ]+( *: *[^: ]+)*) *?)*) *}} *| *POP *)\\]\\] *$/`

Comment: That's really impressive, regex is definitely one of my weaker areas.